# Mysqli prepared statements fetch_array

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am trying to get the below code working but it is not working and giving me the below error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
```

Is there any way to fetch an array with prepared statements?

```
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'], $final_uploads_location)) 
            {
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from test  where `username` = ? and `age` = ? ");
                    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $age);
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->execute();

                    if($stmt->num_rows < 1)
                {
                    $insert = $mysqli->prepare("insert into `test`(`username`, `age`, ) values(?,?)");
                    $insert->bind_param('ss', $username, $age);
                    $insert->execute();

                }
                else
                {
                    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);
                     global $identity;
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You query return false after preparing([mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-returnvalues)). It means that your query has error: undefined fields, unexisting table or something.

Comment: Okay but even if I get that to work the mysqli_fetch_array is going to be a trouble. How do I fetch an array with prepared statements?

Comment: @MarkLubo , explore [mysqli::$error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after query

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the exact query on your database.
I think it is giving you a database error.

Maybe your $mysqli->prepare is returning a "False" value.
By this you where trying to call a "bind_param" function on a boolean data type which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

Try only one at a time ... your bind each statement one after the other. 
And then you execute the query.

Look here [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)